# Error al comparar datos

Tags: sql, vb.net

En un formulario estoy realizando el UPDATE de un registro en la DB. Para realizar esto:

- Selecciono un registro desde un Datagreed-
- Inserto los datos en campos para poder modificarlos. Junto con esto paso los datos a un arreglo.
- Luego modifico los campos que necesito y doy click en un botón "GRABAR"
- Comparo los campos con los del arreglo y así se cuales debo actualizar y cuales no.

El problema se genera al comparar algunos campos, ya que al no haber sido modificados no deberian agregarse a la query, y si esta ocurriendo.

A continuación dejo el código.

Acá asigno los valores a los campos de texto y almaceno los valores en el arreglo.

```
Private Sub gvRegistros_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvRegistros.DoubleClick

    accion = "UPDATE"
    gb_registro.Enabled = True
    'Valido el ID del registro a actualizar!
    If Not gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.Equals("") Then
        idToUpdate = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString() 'Lo asigno a una variable global.
        camposToUpdate(21) = idToUpdate.ToString() ' ID
    End If

    lb_numreg.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value) Then
        cb_un.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(0) = "" ' UN
    Else
        cb_un.Text = Convert.ToString(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value)
        camposToUpdate(0) = Convert.ToString(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value)
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value) Then
        dtp_fecha.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(1) = "" ' FECRET
    Else
        dtp_fecha.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
        camposToUpdate(1) = Convert.ToDateTime(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value) Then
        cb_instalacion.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(2) = "" ' INST
    Else
        cb_instalacion.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(2) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value) Then
        txt_direccion.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(3) = "" ' DIRECC
    Else
        txt_direccion.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(3) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value) Then
        txt_comuna.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(4) = "" ' COMUNA
    Else
        txt_comuna.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(4) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value) Then
        txt_ppu.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(5) = "" ' PPU
    Else
        txt_ppu.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(5) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value) Then
        txt_buses.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(6) = "" ' BUSOPE
    Else
        txt_buses.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(6) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value) Then
        txt_comparacion.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(7) = "" ' COMPRO
    Else
        txt_comparacion.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(7) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value) Then
        txt_marca.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(8) = "" ' MARCA
    Else
        txt_marca.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(8) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value) Then
        txt_modelo.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(9) = "" ' MODELO
    Else
        txt_modelo.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(9) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value) Then
        txt_ano.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(10) = "" ' ANO
    Else
        txt_ano.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(10) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value) Then
        txt_tipveh.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(11) = "" ' TIPVEH
    Else
        txt_tipveh.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(11) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value) Then
        txt_norma.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(12) = "" ' NORMA
    Else
        txt_norma.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(12) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(15).Value) Then
        txt_filtrofab.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(13) = "" ' FABINC
    Else
        txt_filtrofab.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(15).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(13) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(15).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value) Or gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value.Equals("") Or gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value.Equals("N/A") Or gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(17).Value.Equals("-") Or Not gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value.Contains("-") Then
        dtp_instfiltro.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
        camposToUpdate(14) = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() ' FILINC
    Else
        dtp_instfiltro.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value)
        camposToUpdate(14) = Convert.ToDateTime(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value)
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(17).Value) Then
        txt_marcafiltro.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(15) = "" ' MARFIL
    Else
        txt_marcafiltro.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(17).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(15) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(17).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(18).Value) Then
        cb_condicion.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(16) = "" ' CONDIC
    Else
        cb_condicion.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(18).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(16) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(18).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(19).Value) Then
        txt_observaciones.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(17) = "" ' OBSERV
    Else
        txt_observaciones.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(19).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(17) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(19).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(20).Value) Then
        txt_infoextra.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(18) = "" ' EXTINF
    Else
        txt_infoextra.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(20).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(18) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(20).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(21).Value) Then
        txt_responsable.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(19) = "" ' RESPON
    Else
        txt_responsable.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(21).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(19) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(21).Value.ToString()
    End If

    If IsNothing(gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(22).Value) Then
        txt_conductor.Text = ""
        camposToUpdate(20) = "" ' CONDUC
    Else
        txt_conductor.Text = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(22).Value.ToString()
        camposToUpdate(20) = gvRegistros.CurrentRow.Cells(22).Value.ToString()
    End If

    GRABARToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Luego en el boton grabar, veo si inserto un nuevo registro o si actualizo uno. Si accion = "UPDATE", actualizo.

```
Private Sub GRABARToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GRABARToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim query As String
    FormLogin.txt_password.Text = ""
    FormLogin.ShowDialog()

    If accion.Equals("INSERT") Then
        query = crearQueryInsert()
        If query IsNot Nothing Then
            SConexion.Open()
            Dim action_ As New SqlCommand(query, SConexion)
            action_.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Acción finalizada exitosamente.")
            SConexion.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Inserción Fallida", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf accion.Equals("UPDATE") Then
        query = crearQueryUpdate(camposToUpdate)
    Else
        MsgBox("Realice un acción antes de grabar.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Luego en el método "crearQueryUpdate" comparo los valores y creo la query.

```
Private Function crearQueryUpdate(ByVal ParamArray arr() As String) As String
    Dim query As String = ""
    query = "UPDATE Registro SET "

    If String.Compare(arr(0), cb_un.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(0), cb_un.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "UN = '" + arr(0) + "', " ' comparando UN
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(1), Convert.ToString(dtp_fecha.Value)) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(1), Convert.ToString(dtp_fecha.Value)) < 0 Then
        query += "FECRET = '" + arr(1) + "', " ' comparando FECHA
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(2), cb_instalacion.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(2), cb_instalacion.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "INST = '" + arr(2) + "', " ' comparando COD INSTALACION
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(3), txt_direccion.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(3), txt_direccion.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "DIRECC = '" + arr(3) + "', " ' comparando DIRECCION
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(4), txt_comuna.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(4), txt_comuna.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "COMUNA = '" + arr(4) + "', " ' comparando COMUNA
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(5), txt_ppu.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(5), txt_ppu.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "PPU = '" + arr(5) + "', " ' comparando PPU
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(6), txt_buses.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(6), txt_buses.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "BUSOPE = '" + arr(6) + "', " ' comparando BUSES OPERATIVOS
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(7), txt_comparacion.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(7), txt_comparacion.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "COMPRO = '" + arr(7) + "', " ' comparando COMPROBACIÓN
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(8), txt_marca.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(8), txt_marca.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "MARCA = '" + arr(8) + "', " ' comparando MARCA
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(9), txt_modelo.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(9), txt_modelo.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "MODELO = '" + arr(9) + "' " ' comparando MODELO
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(10), txt_ano.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(10), txt_ano.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "ANO = '" + arr(10) + "', " ' comparando AÑO
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(11), txt_tipveh.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(11), txt_tipveh.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "TIPVEH = '" + arr(11) + "', " ' comparando TIPO VEHICULO
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(12), txt_norma.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(12), txt_norma.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "NORMA = '" + arr(12) + "', " ' comparando NORMA
    End If

    If String.Compare(Convert.ToString(arr(13)), Convert.ToString(txt_filtrofab.Text)) > 0 Or String.Compare(Convert.ToString(arr(13)), Convert.ToString(txt_filtrofab.Text)) < 0 Then
        query += "FABINC = '" + arr(13) + "', " ' comparando FILTRO FAB INC
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(14), Convert.ToString(dtp_instfiltro.Value)) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(14), Convert.ToString(dtp_instfiltro.Value)) < 0 Then
        query += "FILINC = '" + arr(14) + "', " ' comparando FECHA INST. FILTRO
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(15), txt_marcafiltro.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(15), txt_marcafiltro.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "MARFIL = '" + arr(15) + "', " ' comparando MARCA FILTRO
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(16), cb_condicion.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(16), cb_condicion.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "CONDIC = '" + arr(16) + "', " ' comparando CONDICION
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(17), txt_observaciones.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(17), txt_observaciones.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "OBSERV = '" + arr(17) + "', " ' comparando OBSERVACIONES
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(18), txt_infoextra.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(18), txt_infoextra.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "EXTINF = '" + arr(18) + "', " ' comparando INFORMACIÓN EXTRA
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(19), txt_responsable.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(19), txt_responsable.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "RESPON = '" + arr(19) + "' " ' comparando RESPONSABLE
    End If

    If String.Compare(arr(20), txt_conductor.Text) > 0 Or String.Compare(arr(20), txt_conductor.Text) < 0 Then
        query += "CONDUC = '" + arr(20) + "', " ' comparando CONDUCTOR
    End If

    'query = query.TrimEnd(", ")
    If query.Length > 2 Then
        query = Convert.ToString(query.Remove(query.Length - 2))
        query += " WHERE ID = '" + Convert.ToString(idToUpdate) + "' "
    Else
        query = ""
    End If

    MsgBox(query)

    'Return query
End Function
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Hay alguna razon en especial por la que usas `String.Compare` cuando puedes usar el `Equals` o los operadores `=` y `<>` ?

Comment: No hay ninguna razón en particular. De hecho los probé y los resultados no fueron tan distintos.

Comment: Podes mostrar casos en los que fallan las comparaciones? no deberias agregar en el compare un true para que ignore las mayusculas?

Comment: igual la pregunta seria, estas haciendo esas comparaciones tratando de evitar que cosa en la bd? pq hacer el update de todo el registro no deberia afectar la performance de la db, salvo que haga algo raro ella misma. el registro cuando se actualiza se devuelve entero y se vuelve a grabar entero...

Comment: Quiero actualizar solo el campo que se modifico dentro del registro.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de resolver el problema. Se generaba que al pasar a la grilla toma como mayusculas y los valores originales estan con mayusculas y minusculas.

Corregido eso funciono perfectamente.

Saludos.